# Can CDI dependency injection be optional?

Tags: dependency-injection, cdi

In Spring DI, declaring an autowired field as Optional enables a client to not inject any value to it. Is this possible using Java EE's CDI? I tried Optional and it fails. I want to know if there is an equivalent mechanism I can use.

Here is what I tried:

```
public class OmeletteMaker implements EggMaker{
        public static void main(String[] args){
        WeldContainer container = new Weld().initialize();
        OmeletteMaker omeletteMaker = container.instance().select(OmeletteMaker.class).get();
    }

    @Inject
    Optional<Vegetable> vegetable;
}
```

I get an error message:
Exception in thread "main" org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [Optional] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject cafeteria.OmeletteMaker.vegetable]

Comment: According to my searches, optional should work (never used it). But like [ask] states, post what you tried in [mcve] flavour and post what you search results were and why they did not help (post 'behaviour', 'did not work' is not behaviour. And also post version and implementation info

Comment: Thanks, I added a description of what I tried.

Comment: Can't find the link quickly but from what I remember it should be `Instance<Vegetable>`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are many questions lurking in this seemingly simple question.  I'll try to answer them bearing in mind the spirit of the question.

First, as a general rule, if you `@Inject` a `Fred`, that `Fred` cannot be `null` unless `Fred` is in `@Dependent` scope, and even then a producer method or custom bean will have to explicitly be written to return `null`.  There are edge cases but in all modern CDI implementations this is a good rule of thumb to bear in mind.

Second, `Optional` isn't special.  From the standpoint of CDI, an `Optional` is just another Java object, so see my first statement above.  If you have something that produces an `Optional` (like a producer method) then it cannot make a `null` `Optional` (unless, again, the production is defined to be in the `@Dependent` scope—and if you were writing such a method to make `Optional` instances and returning `null` you are definitely going to confuse your users).  If you are in control of producing `Optional` instances, then you can make them any way you like.

Third, in case you want to test to see if there is a managed bean or a producer of some kind for a `Fred`, you can, as one of the comments on your question indicates, inject a `Provider<Fred>` or an `Instance<Fred>`.  These are "made" by the container automatically: you don't have to write anything special to produce them yourself.  A `Provider<Fred>` is an accessor of `Fred` instances and does not attempt to acquire an instance until its `get()` method is called. 
 An `Instance` is a `Provider` and an `Iterable` of all known `Fred`s and can additionally tell you whether (a) it is "unsatisfied"—there are no producers of `Fred` at all—and (b) it is "resolvable"—i.e. there is exactly one producer of `Fred`.

Fourth, the common idiom in cases where you want to see if something is there is to inject an `Instance` parameterized with the type you want, and then check its [`isResolvable()`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/2.0/apidocs/javax/enterprise/inject/Instance.html#isResolvable--) method.  If that returns `true`, then you can call its `get()` method and trust that its return value will be non-`null` (assuming the thing it makes is not in `@Dependent` scope).

I hope this is helpful!

Comment: Great summary of something I could not find in StackOverflow.

Comment: _" and even then a producer method or custom bean will have to explicitly be written to return null. There are edge cases but in all modern CDI implementations this is a good rule of thumb to bear in mind."_ what if inject interfaces and have no implementation?

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer. It both answers my initial question and covers additional topics I didn't understand!

Comment: @Kukeltje if you have `@Inject private Fred fred` and there is nothing known to CDI that implements `Fred` then you will get an unsatisfied dependency error at startup.

Comment: @LiairdNelson: Yes, that I understand, but I was talking about the `Instance` and_"it is "unsatisfied"—there are no producers of Fred at all—"_

Comment: @Kukeltje If I am understanding you correctly: if you have `@Inject private Instance<Fred> fredInstance`, `fredInstance` will always be non-`null`.  If you call `get()` on it and there are no `Fred`s in CDI's world then you'll get an unsatisfied dependency error.  If you call `isUnsatisfied()` on it it will return `true`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. the support of `@Inject Optional<Fred>` would make a good thing for a CDI extension now think of it (could it be done? (Less technical))

Comment: "There are edge cases but in all modern CDI implementations this is a good rule of thumb to bear in mind."

OSGi is quite modern and it allows optional injections and also in OSGi services can come and go during runtime. So you actual might end up with zero provided instances for a service f.e. . But yes, it is no Jakarta EE CDI implementation if this is what you meant.